# Ping not working for ubuntu virtual machines on azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, hadoop

I created 2 ubuntu virtual machines on azure and I can log into one machine from the other using "ssh azureuser@xyz.cloudapp.net" but pinging one virtual machine from another gives no response. same thing with curl.

```
ping xyz.cloudapp.net 
curl xyz.cloudapp.net
```

Modifying the /etc/hosts file with the internal ip addresses of the virtual machines doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ICMP (Ping) is blocked in Azure so by design this will fail.  You can get this to work depending on how you are setting up your network and what you are trying to ping.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0669112c-a6dd-4290-bcde-9ce7b9d60d80/how-do-i-enable-pinging-a-vm for more details:

> •Ping external address from Azure VM - does not work as Azure does not
> permit outbound ICMP
>
> •Ping Azure VM from external address - does not work as Azure does not
> permit inbound ICMP
>
> •Ping between Azure VMs using internal IP (DIP) - works, but guest OS
> firewall must be configured to allow it as by default ICMP is blocked
> by the guest.
>
> •Ping between Azure VM and on-premise through Azure Connect
> (point-to-point IPSec VPN tunnel) or Virtual Network Gateway
> (site-to-site IPSec VPN tunnel) - works, but guest OS firewall must be
> configured to allow it as by default ICMP is blocked by the guest.
>
> To allow ICMP on a Windows VM, from an elevated command prompt, run:
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv6" dir=in action=allow
> enable=yes protocol=icmpv6  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule
> name="ICMPV4" dir=in action=allow enable=yes protocol=icmpv4

**UPDATE 2021**: As of 2021, you can ping to your azure virtual machine by opening the ICMP port.
Just go to Azure Portal > Virtual Machines > Select your Virtual Machine > Networking > Add inbound port rule > Select ICMP under Protocol (customize as per your needs) > Add

Answer (score 1):

You can try `hping3` ping host on port number,

```
sudo apt-get install hping3
root@compare:~# sudo hping3 -S -p 80 google.com
HPING google.com (eth0 216.58.196.174): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=44 ip=216.58.196.174 ttl=53 id=20026 sport=80 flags=SA seq=0 win=42900 rtt=32.8 ms
len=44 ip=216.58.196.174 ttl=53 id=34969 sport=80 flags=SA seq=1 win=42900 rtt=36.6 ms
len=44 ip=216.58.196.174 ttl=53 id=14912 sport=80 flags=SA seq=2 win=42900 rtt=32.6 ms
len=44 ip=216.58.196.174 ttl=53 id=60826 sport=80 flags=SA seq=3 win=42900 rtt=32.5 ms
len=44 ip=216.58.196.174 ttl=53 id=5138 sport=80 flags=SA seq=4 win=42900 rtt=32.3 ms
^C
--- google.com hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 32.3/33.4/36.6 ms
root@compare:~#
```

Comment: Also, we can check from outside 
`root@mail:/home/hrishi# sudo hping3 -S -p 80 1we1.cloudapp.net
HPING 1we1.cloudapp.net (eth0 23.97.74.251): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=46 ip=23.97.74.251 ttl=50 DF id=0 sport=80 flags=SA seq=0 win=29200 rtt=111.9 ms
len=46 ip=23.97.74.251 ttl=50 DF id=0 sport=80 flags=SA seq=1 win=29200 rtt=112.7 ms
^C
--- 1we1.cloudapp.net hping statistic ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 111.9/112.3/112.7 ms
root@mail:/home/hrishi#`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2021:**
As of 2021, you can ping to your azure virtual machine by opening the ICMP port.

Just go to Azure Portal > Virtual Machines > Select your Virtual Machine > Networking > Add inbound port rule > Select ICMP under Protocol (customize as per your needs) > Add

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2022**
To launch ping as a standard user, either use the count -c option `ping -c 4 google.com`, or change the file permission of `/bin/ping` by adding the SUID bit.

On a Azure virtual machine, with UBUNTU 20.04 or 22.04, the ping program has these permissions:
 `ls -la /bin/ping`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72776 Jan 30  2020 ping*`
Therefore, in order to run ping, you must have root privileges.

This means that if you elevate your privileges to root, you can use ping
`$ sudo su`
`# ping google.com`
`PING google.com (142.251.36.14) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from ams15s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.36.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=2.42 ms`
CTRL-C to exit.

Ping from a VM on azure can be done also in two other ways:

1. using the -c count options, as a normal user
   `$ ping -c 4 google.com`
2. By changing the SUID bit of the ping file, then every user will run the ping program with root privileges
   `# chmod 4755 /bin/ping`
   Then, you can do the ping with normal user privileges
   `$ ping google.com`

Comment: Instead of a suid bit, should use setcap to allow only specific subset of root-privileges needed (e.g. `setcap cap_net_raw+ep /bin/ping`)